Split mrc file into pieces by using DM script
I have a mrc file, which contains 10 pieces. After loading into DM, I can browser the pieces by using the left and right arrow. I'd like to use DM script to read the mrc file and then save each piece into a separated file. Is that possible?

Slightly confused. What do you mean by using the left and right arrow ? On the Slice palette or where? It could be helpful if you could provide access to some dummy-MRC file that shows what you mean, as I'm not used to working with this data format.
What are 10 "pieces" mean exactly?

Sorry for the ambiguity. For the mrc format, it may contain several images with the same size. For example, when you use in-situ mode to collect images, GMS will save every image into a single file. Mrc format can save all these images into one file. I need to split these images in mrc file, and save each into one file. For the left and right arrow, I mean the arrow key in the keyboard. Please download the test mrc file from this website: https://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/empiar/world_availability/10146/data/

I found my requirement can be achieved by File->Save as series. I will check whether there is any corresponding command

It have been solved by slice2 command. I found the solution in your great tutorial.

Hi ChenZX, I've noticed that you have a couple of questions on site which are still marked "unanswerd".  Could you maybe revise them and either amend with still open questions or mark them as answered? (By clicking the check-symbol underneath the voting buttons, next to the answer you think is the best.)

Sorry. I forgot. I will mark them as answered soon.

I found the ticks of my choosed answers disappeared. I don't know what happened.

How weird! I can see that all your questions appear indeed "unanswered"...

@BmyGuest One possibility is I only choose your answer or Mike's answer as the best answer. The system thought we are cheating.

That can certainly be. ArtificialUnIntelligence at work :c)

Glad you've solved it yourself by now. In order to have some answer here on StackOverflow as well, this is how I would do it. (Tested with your example file)
string path = "C:\\temp\\test.mrc"

if ( !OpenDialog( NULL , "Load MRC stack from" , path , path ) ) exit(0)

image stack := NewImageDocumentFromFile(path).ImageDocumentGetRootImage()
if ( !stack.ImageIsValid() )
    Throw("Could not read file:\n"+path)
    
//stack.ShowImage()
if ( 3 != stack.ImageGetNumDimensions() )
    Throw("File is not a 3D stack.")
    
number sx,sy,sz
stack.ImageGetDimensionSizes(sx,sy,sz)

string folder = PathExtractDirectory(path,0)
string baseName = PathExtractBasename(path,0)

// Split and save
for(number i=0;i<sz;i++){
    
    image img := stack.slice2(0,0,i, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1).ImageClone()
    string filePath = folder+basename+"_"+i
    OpenAndSetProgressWindow("Saving file "+(i+1)+" / "+sz,filepath,"")
    img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument().ImageDocumentSaveToFile( "Gatan Format", filePath)
    Result("\n saved: "+filePath)
}

CloseProgressWindow()

